# How can I create a union of NSOrderedSets?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I can create a union of NSSets using setByAddingObjectsFromSet: but there is no equivalent method in NSOrderedSet. I could temporarily convert to NSSets to perform the union but would expect then to lose order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like [`unionOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableOrderedSet/addObject:) from `NSMutableOrderedSet`.

Comment: I do, a lot. Thank you. I was overlooking the mutable part of what I was doing and didn't realise there was an NSMutableOrderedSet. Thank you Adam.